# IPad gfx optimization: Is UIView taking rendering time if its alpha is set to zero?

Tags: ipad, ios

For performance optimization reasons I'd like to know: does an UIView take up rendering time if its alpha is set to zero? Or should I remove those uiiews that are completely transparent?

Pom

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a late answer, but my experience is that the view is not drawn when alpha is set to 0. At least not for CGAffineTransform.